# Cloud function returns different results depending on platform

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've got a Parse Cloud Code function that is a simple query to ask for a root object and gets its children objects and their children objects (3 layers of object hierarchy).

```
Set
|--> Group
     |--> Item
```

I am doing it this way because the `Set` might already be on the device, and I cannot find a reliable way to make sure I have the latest copy. `fetchInBackground...` might work, except you can't do the `include` that I need to do to get the children/grandchildren. (I can't figure out why Parse hasn't added this feature. I cannot tell you how many times I have wanted to to say "update this object, including these child objects"!)

Anyway, the Cloud Code function is working, but producing weird results:

1. When I run the query from the REST API Console, I get all of the data that I expect. Specifically, I get the 1 `Set`, the 3 `Group` objects that belong to that set, and the `Item` objects that belong to each `Group`. Specifically, the 3rd `Group` of the `Set` contains 67 `Item` objects.
2. When I run the query from an iOS device (or simulator), the 3rd `Group` is consistently returned with 51 `Item` objects. Interestingly, this **WAS** true before the data model was updated on the server.

So, in spite of my best efforts, I can't seem to update the data model that has been pinned on my device to reflect the changes that have been made on the server. What has me **REALLY** baffled is that fact that, in spite of calling a Cloud Code function, the on-device data model is returned.

I am assuming that when the object is returned from the function, it sees that the object is already pinned and doesn't incorporate the new data from the server. What I can't figure out is how to get around this. I want the data pinned, because I don't want to have to manage my own local data store (though I guess I will if necessary). I've tried unpinning the `Set` object just before calling the Cloud Code function, but that doesn't change the results, even if I run the `unpin` call synchronously.

I have just spent several hours trying to do my own refresh sequence, like this:

1. Refresh the `Set`
2. Iterate the `Group` objects of the `Set`, refreshing them
3. Iterate the `Item` objects of each `Group`, refreshing them

Though this appears to work well as the process is executing, once I get to the end of the process, the 2nd and 3rd level data is not retained.

I feel like this should be a trivial implementation. A lot of people have asked for this feature. Has anyone figured out basically, how to execute a "fetch with include"?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `object ID` of the `set` that you want to update, you can create a query on the `set` class and constrain the `object ID`. Then you can use the `includeKey:` method to grab the relevant data and then fetch the data.

Another option would be to first fetch the set object, then fetch its children. This would require multiple nested network requests however.

Comment: This is exactly what I described in my question. When I do this, the object I get back seems to be discarded favor of the item that is already in the local data store.

Comment: Have you tried the object ID query? I would also try reinstalling the app (delete on phone) to see if your LDS has bad data in it or something.

Comment: Yes. There does not appear to be any way to ignore the results that are already in the local data store. And I cannot simply do a fetchInBackground because that does not allow me to get child and especially grand child objects.